# java* setlocation of default screen to (0,0)

Tags: java, location, this

im trying to change the location of my default frame to the point 0,0
But when I use this. it doesn't give suggestions. When I try to do this.setLocation(0,0);
it gives an error.
I dont know how to set my first frame as a Jframe like:

```
    Jframe frame = MYFRAME??;
```

*Im using swing
thank you

Comment: Could You post the code what You have done?

Answer (score 1):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLocation(0,0);
```

But don't put it there.  See [How to best position Swing GUIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7143287/418556) (`setLocationByPlatform(true)`) for a better alternative.

[image]

Comment: yes  but I dont want a new frame, I want the same frame to move

Comment: What do I do if I want to move the default frame?

Comment: I don't really understand that.  1) Do you have more than one frame in the app.? 2) By 'I' do you mean the programmer or user? 3) By move do you mean muse or code?

Comment: i just have one frame, I want to set the startlocation to 0,0

Comment: That answer only had 3 frames to demonstrate the effect.  I showed in **this** answer how to set the location of 1 frame to the upper left corner of the screen.  I do not understand why you are still asking questions & making comments.